# What can I use instead of Where clause in Asyn method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have a project in c# and Entity Framework. I need to convert some of the methods of Repository to Async. I have problem to converting this method, not sure what I can use instead of Where clause.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetProductByYearIdAsync(int yearId)
    {
        return await ApplicationsContext.Product.Where(product=> product.YearId == yearId);
    }
```

when I use this it gave me error that cannot await iQueryable. when I use FirstOrDefaultAsync I lot know how to convert to IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Where` does not actually execute the query, so there is nothing "asynchronous" about invoking `Where`. You need to invoke `ToListAsync` which actually executes the query asynchronously.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetProductByYearIdAsync(int yearId)
{
    return await ApplicationsContext.Product
        .Where(product=> product.YearId == yearId).ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `.ToListAsync()` on the end. That is the actual asyncronous operation, not the `.Where(`

Note you must make sure that the assembly is refrencing the `EntityFramework` dll and you have the namespace  `System.Data.Entity` included in a using statement because this is [a extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx).